I am training LSTM model for flood water level prediction. How to make the performance of the model better?

from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, OneHotEncoder,MinMaxScaler
from keras.models import Sequential 
from keras.layers import Dense 
import keras
from keras.layers import LSTM,Activation,Dropout
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error

learning_rate = 0.001

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(30, input_shape=(X_train.shape[1], X_train.shape[2])))    # input_shape=(no. of i/p, dimension), result=(1,50)
# test
model.add(Dense(512,name='FC1'))  #256
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(Dense(512))  #256
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(Dense(256))  #256
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(Dense(128))  #256
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
# end
model.add(Dense(1, activation='relu'))

msle = MeanSquaredLogarithmicError()
optimizer = Adam(learning_rate=learning_rate)
model.compile(loss=msle, optimizer=optimizer, metrics=[msle])

this is the code to the model
